Data frames - How does .set_row_names() work?
In 24.4.2 as.data.frame(), Hadley defines
quickdf <- function(l) {
  class(l) <- "data.frame"
  attr(l, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(length(l[[1]]))
  l
}

and compares
l <- lapply(1:26, function(i) runif(1e3))
names(l) <- letters

bench::mark(
  as.data.frame = as.data.frame(l),
  quick_df      = quickdf(l)
)[c("expression", "min", "median", "itr/sec", "n_gc")]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   expression         min   median `itr/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl>
#> 1 as.data.frame   1.97ms    2.1ms      471.
#> 2 quick_df       17.18µs   19.4µs    48584.

I do not understand
attr(L,'row.names') <- .set_row_names(length(L[[1]]))

.set_row_names(length(L[[1]]))
# returns NA, -1000


@Friede what do you mean that it does not ship with base R? The function exists in the base namespace. Its simply concatenates NA and -n where n is size. eg .set_row_names(3) should output c(NA, -3L)

@Friede Thanks, I am coufused the df L more than 2 rows , but .set_row_names(length(L[[1]])) , return only  NA  and -1000. There are not match

I have re-shaped your question and edited the source in (quite important). A few weeks ago, user @SamR (I think) wrote an answer w.r.t. the internal storage of row names. I cannot find, therefore the ping.

@Friede you don't get a ping when someone @ mentions a post you haven't commented on. But felicitously I have come across this minutes after your comment :). I think you're talking about Why does adding attributes to a dataframe take longer with large dataframes?. To the OP, basically this function just stores row names as c(NA, 1000) rather than a vector of length 1000. Which is more efficient when (as I think is mostly the case these days) you're not using them.

@anderwyang does the linked post answer your question? I'm not sure if it's a duplicate. It's not the same question but I think the answer contains the answer to this question.

A beautiful, thank you @SamR.

This is an interesting question. Having gone through the C code, I noticed that the rownames of dataframes are stored in a compacted format considered to be a short rowname. eg run .Internal(shortRowNames(iris, 0)) and you will see that it produces NA, -150.  Changing the type ie .Internal(shortRowNames(iris, 2)) gives the number of rows. Notice that the - has no impact since in the internal code they use absolute value. You can also check the row_names_gets C function. Although, I have not seen where the expansion takes place. ie where they use seq() to generate the rownames.

@Onyambu No need for internal functions. See help(".row_names_info").

@Roland that function directed me to shortRowNames. Notice that .row_names_info calls shortRowNames

@SamR  The linked post and your comments are useful, got it . Thanks!
